# Show Addressbook with UISegmentController in Nevigationbar

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook, uisegmentedcontrol, mainwindow

**TASK :**

```
I want to show my all contact in one UItable and Which parts all contacts  with UISegmentcontroller which is in Nevigationbar.

My Application is Tabbar Application so When I show my UISegmentController I have to add it in my Mainwindow xib . Becoz of that I cant access my Contactview data from app delegate file .
```

I want to make My Addressbook just Look like app called "Viber [(http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/viber-free-phone-calls-text/id382617920?mt=8)](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/viber-free-phone-calls-text/id382617920?mt=8)"

..

So Just need help to Add that UISegmentController in my MainWindow.xib . It shows there but i cant access My IBAction functions from there and also I cant Fatch data from my ContactviewController.m

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are attaching the touchupinside with IBAction from your xib. Attatch it with valueChanged event.

Comment: no I am not doing that ..I have already use Value Changed . My main issue is that How could I Give one segment to All data and another to Another Table .. My all contacts come from one view and I dont know how to use that data in my App-delegate file .. Now u got it sir  .. ??

Comment: I want to call Whole Address book on one segment part and Some few selected contacts to another Segment part .. M having two Segment in one tabbar view (in its nevigation bar) .. And M calling all that contact data from another view . I want to call it from App-delegate ..